# Processing JSON data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my JSON data (also available [here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values?alt=json)):

```
[{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cokwr"},"updated":{"$t":"2018-06-23T22:12:49.197Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Row: 2"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"_cokwr: Heading 1"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cokwr"}],"gsx$_cokwr":{"$t":"Heading 1"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cpzh4"},"updated":{"$t":"2018-06-23T22:12:49.197Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Row: 3"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"_cokwr: John, _cpzh4: $9.00"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cpzh4"}],"gsx$_cokwr":{"$t":"John"},"gsx$_cpzh4":{"$t":"$9.00"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cre1l"},"updated":{"$t":"2018-06-23T22:12:49.197Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Row: 4"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"_cokwr: Elijah, _cpzh4: $12.00"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cre1l"}],"gsx$_cokwr":{"$t":"Elijah"},"gsx$_cpzh4":{"$t":"$12.00"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/chk2m"},"updated":{"$t":"2018-06-23T22:12:49.197Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Row: 5"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"_cokwr: Andrew, _cpzh4: $1.00"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/chk2m"}],"gsx$_cokwr":{"$t":"Andrew"},"gsx$_cpzh4":{"$t":"$1.00"}}]
```

It's basically a Google Spreadsheet in JSON format.

What I am trying to get is the money (starting with $). In the Google Sheet, it's only in column C. Particularly right now I try to get the "$12.00" (cell: *C4*).

I tried `$(".results").prepend('<b>'+data.feed.entry.gsx$_cpzh4.$t+'</b>');` and got:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$t' of undefined

Note: Please keep your answers simple since I just started learning about javascript & jquery 12 hours ago.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest working code snippet** necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @LGSon
desired behavior: _try to get the "$12.00" (cell: C4)_
Specific problem or error: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$t' of undefined_
shortest working code snippet: `$(".results").prepend('<b>'+data.feed.entry.gsx$_cpzh4.$t+'</b>');`
If you are trying to say that the JSON data is long, then:
1) I am a beginner and don't know how to create a snippet out of it necessary to reproduce my issue
2) It's just a chunk of data that can be easily copy-pasted in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: In general, it doesn't matter whether the _poster of a question_ is a beginner or not, for anyone to be able to provide a proper answer a code snippet reproducing the issue is required. Also, one is suppose to provide a [mcve], as this link explains more about, and that again regardless of one's skills. (you got lucky in this case though, where someone decide to write up such snippet, but don't depend on it, as often no one will and such question generally gets downvoted/closed)

Comment: @LGSon I see. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things

- First of all the `entry` is an array.
- and the property you are trying to access `gsx$_cpzh4` does not exist in all the objects inside the `entry` array.

You need to iterate using simple `forEach` and access all the objects which have the property defined by using `.hasOwnProperty()`, a simple console print demo is given below using your provided `json` you can see it prints the prices using `entry.gsx$_cpzh4.$t` for all the entries inside the `entry` array and skips those that don't have that property defined.

```
//iterate over al lthe entries
data.feed.entry.forEach(function(entry) {
  //if it has the property defined with name gsx$_cpzh4
  if (entry.hasOwnProperty('gsx$_cpzh4')) {
    //print the prices
    console.log(entry['gsx$_cpzh4'].$t);
  }
});
```

```js
let data = {
  "version": "1.0",
  "encoding": "UTF-8",
  "feed": {
    "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
    "xmlns$openSearch": "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/",
    "xmlns$gsx": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended",
    "id": {
      "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values"
    },
    "updated": {
      "$t": "2018-06-23T22:12:49.197Z"
    },
    "category": [{
      "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
      "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
    }],
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "$t": "Sheet1"
    },
    "link": [{
        "rel": "alternate",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/pubhtml"
      },
      {
        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values"
      },
      {
        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values"
      },
      {
        "rel": "self",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values?alt=json"
      }
    ],
    "author": [{
      "name": {
        "$t": "gem7008"
      },
      "email": {
        "$t": "gem7008@gmail.com"
      }
    }],
    "openSearch$totalResults": {
      "$t": "4"
    },
    "openSearch$startIndex": {
      "$t": "1"
    },
    "entry": [{
        "id": {
          "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cokwr"
        },
        "updated": {
          "$t": "2018-06-23T22:12:49.197Z"
        },
        "category": [{
          "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
          "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
        }],
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "$t": "Row: 2"
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "$t": "_cokwr: Heading 1"
        },
        "link": [{
          "rel": "self",
          "type": "application/atom+xml",
          "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cokwr"
        }],
        "gsx$_cokwr": {
          "$t": "Heading 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": {
          "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cpzh4"
        },
        "updated": {
          "$t": "2018-06-23T22:12:49.197Z"
        },
        "category": [{
          "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
          "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
        }],
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "$t": "Row: 3"
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "$t": "_cokwr: John, _cpzh4: $9.00"
        },
        "link": [{
          "rel": "self",
          "type": "application/atom+xml",
          "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cpzh4"
        }],
        "gsx$_cokwr": {
          "$t": "John"
        },
        "gsx$_cpzh4": {
          "$t": "$9.00"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": {
          "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cre1l"
        },
        "updated": {
          "$t": "2018-06-23T22:12:49.197Z"
        },
        "category": [{
          "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
          "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
        }],
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "$t": "Row: 4"
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "$t": "_cokwr: Elijah, _cpzh4: $12.00"
        },
        "link": [{
          "rel": "self",
          "type": "application/atom+xml",
          "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/cre1l"
        }],
        "gsx$_cokwr": {
          "$t": "Elijah"
        },
        "gsx$_cpzh4": {
          "$t": "$12.00"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": {
          "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/chk2m"
        },
        "updated": {
          "$t": "2018-06-23T22:12:49.197Z"
        },
        "category": [{
          "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
          "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
        }],
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "$t": "Row: 5"
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "$t": "_cokwr: Andrew, _cpzh4: $1.00"
        },
        "link": [{
          "rel": "self",
          "type": "application/atom+xml",
          "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12fmjZfRgJHlSulaWQdmvaz1yinmwaTwsdHsOzRfYNBE/od6/public/values/chk2m"
        }],
        "gsx$_cokwr": {
          "$t": "Andrew"
        },
        "gsx$_cpzh4": {
          "$t": "$1.00"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

data.feed.entry.forEach(function(entry) {
  if (entry.hasOwnProperty('gsx$_cpzh4')) {
    console.log(entry['gsx$_cpzh4'].$t);
    $(".results").prepend('<b>' + entry['gsx$_cpzh4'].$t + '</b>')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">

</div>
```